# RuneTimeError: Can't start new thread, threading library

Tags: python, multithreading

So, in this code I am testing some multi threading to speed up my code.  If I have a large number of tasks in queue I get `RuneTimeError: Can't start new thread` error.  For example, `range(0,100)` works, but `range(0,1000)` won't work.  I am using `threading.Semaphore(4)` and this is correctly working, only processing 4 threads at a time, tested this is working.   I know why I am getting this error, because even though I am using `threading.Semaphore` it still technically starts all the threads at the start, but just pauses them until it's the threads turn to run and starting 1000 threads at the same time is to much for the PC to handle.  Is there anyway to fix this problem? (Also, yes, I know about GIL)

```
def thread_test():
    threads = []
    for t in self.tasks:
        t = threading.Thread(target=utils.compareV2.run_compare_temp, args=t)        
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

for x in range(0,100):
    self.tasks.append(("arg1","arg2"))

thread_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting 1000 threads and then only letting 4 do any work at a time, start 4 threads and let them all do work.

What are the extra 996 threads buying you?

They're using memory and putting pressure on the system's scheduler.

The reason you get the `RuntimeError` is probably that you've run out of memory for the call stacks for all of those threads.  The default limit varies by platform but it's probably something close to 8MiB.  A thousand of those and you're up around 8GiB... just for *stack* space.

You can reduce the amount of memory available for the call stack of each thread with `threading.stack_size(...)`.  This will let you fit more threads on your system (but be sure you don't set it below the amount of stack space you actually need or you'll crash your process).

Most likely, what you actually want is a number of *processes* close to the number of physical cores on your host or a threading system that's more light-weight than what the `threading` module gives you.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up having to write my own queue wrapper for the threading library.  Was very surprised they didn't have something like that built in, closest they had was `semaphore`

Comment: You didn't say anything about queues in your question so I'm not sure what this comment means.